# How do you calculate conditional expectation for a single continuous r.v.?

Tags: probability

So if you have a distribution `fx(x)` and you observed x=a, how do you calculate `E{x | x=a} = integral (x*fx(x|x=a) from -inf to inf`, or more specifically, `fx(x|x=a)`

I am having trouble when using Bayes or finding `Fx(x|x=a)` because I end up with `P(x=a)` which is just a constant.  Is there a simple example somewhere? Searching only leads me to bivariate distributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood your problem: your conditional density is just a Dirac delta function in $x=a$:

$$f_x(x|x=a) =\delta(x-a)$$

Hence, $E(x | x=a) = a$ 
... as intuition says.

If you want to apply the definition, you can use a limiting procedure (because, for a continuous variable the event $X=a$ has actually zero probability), considering instead the event that $X$ takes a value around $a$, in a neighborhood of length $dx$.
But that's not necessary. You already know that the joint probability (the one that goes into the numerator) is zero if $x\ne a$. Hence, as the conditional density must integrate to one, it must be a dirac delta function.

Comment: Please check your post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation, makes sense to me.